# What can this component be?

Tags: diodes

I have [this anemometer (wind speed meter)](http://s.campbellsci.com/documents/cr/product-brochures/b_p2546a.pdf).

They provide some specs. But not the circuitry. It basically outputs pulses via a reed switch.

So I opened this instrument to see its circuitry. Here is what I saw inside.

First of all there is no indicator on the components. I mean I am guessing one is a diode an the other is the series resistor. The components are totally black and I read ..V on it, but its not clear, that's all.

On their website it says 330 ohm series resistance. So I'm more sure about which one is the the resistor.

When the switch is on, there is pot. diff. on R2 and when the switch is off there is no pot. diff.

The resistor looks like a chip resistor IEE written on it.

Anyway, my question if one of the component is a diode why can be the reason it is used for.

Since there is no inductive load it is not used for flyback purpose. Can it be a regulator?

Here is how it looks like (the circuitry is in the red window, rest is for measurement):

[image: Schematic]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about a photo?

Comment: "1EE" is actually "331" upside-down. This is the standard marking for a 330-ohm resistor.

Comment: I will provide a photo today. The ins. is not with me at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have the diode placed upside down here? That could make it a regulator, if it were a Zener type of diode.

Comment: Thats what Im doubting. It can be a zener diode to regulate the voltage for not burning the reedswitch. Maybe but I am not sure. I will try to take a photo soon.

Comment: Maybe it's a TVS for protecting the reed switch.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany what would it be different if it is tvs instead of a zener?

Comment: A TVS is like a zener on steroids. Able to absorb enormous punishment.

Comment: I will provide a photo soon. maybe you guys would have a better idea then. thanks

Comment: In your diagram, where is the display or read-out device connected?  Having that inforamtion would allow us to make a (somewhat) educated guess as to the function of the components.

Comment: you see R2 in the diagram. I read the pulses/freq. (or should I say on off voltage readings) from the ends of this resistor. the actual circuit of the instrument is in the red rectangle. the rest is cabling and powering

Comment: I have from a good source: "It’s most likely just a small filter cap to help remove any line noise picked up through the excitation voltage wiring (or to remove switch bounce, which this anemometer really touts as a feature)."

Comment: hello all again, I just uploaded 2 photos from the little PCB. Views both from up and down. How does it look like to you? A diode?

Comment: Must get eyes checked... so blurry. I'd say it's a diode based on the silkscreen "D1" but can't really tell with the black covering on it.

Comment: yes but I cannot even read it with naked eyes because nothing seems to be written on it:(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many anemometer installations require long wiring runs, which, even for distant lightning strikes, are subject to high voltage spikes. Further, these long lengths of cable at the rated 30V DC can have inductive effects, so while the PCB doesn't include an inductive part, it could still be subject to inductive kickback which the diode will handle, preventing contact degradation.

A TVS diode in parallel with the reed switch helps protect the reed from arcs from either high voltage events, or possible inductive issues with the measuring equipment or long cable length.

While most TVS diodes optimize for low capacitance, you can get TVS diodes with enough capacitance to accommodate the bounce of a low-bounce reed relay.  With a good magnet design you can lower the bounce even further so the TVS capacitance is enough to manage the bounce altogether. It's possible this part is playing two roles.

Given that it's marked `D1`, this is my guess. You could put it into a curve tracer to verify, though if it is a TVS diode you'll need a high voltage curve tracer.

Comment: thanks, but i didn't get one thing. if it is a surface mount TVS diode, depending on my diagram(assuming my drawing based on the PCB is right), how come it is blocking the reverse polarization? i can understand it can regulate/clamp but don't we need a series diode for reverse polarization protection?

Answer (score 0):

As guys in comments said - IEE is 331 upside down. 330R resistor.

Other part is probably TVS that protects your measurement equimpent from overvolting and reverse polarisation.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. If so the difference between TVS and Zener is that Zener only takes care of over voltage but TVS takes care of both over voltage and reverse polarization? Is that right?

Comment: Thats right. You can read more here:http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AND8424-D.PDF

Zener diode is... diffrent. It can protect too, but its just diffrent.

Comment: but i didn't get one thing. if it is a surface mount TVS diode, depending on my diagram(assuming my drawing based on the PCB is right), how come it is blocking the reverse polarization? i can understand it can regulate/clamp but don't we need a series diode for reverse polarization protection?

Comment: @user16307 - A TVS is somewhat like two opposing direction zeners in series. It doesn't conduct until you exceed the breakdown voltage in *either* direction. For example, a 20V TVS wouldn't begin conducting until you exceed +20V *or* -20V. If your circuit uses 5V, it would have no effect during normal operation.

Comment: Depending on your application, this may be acceptable. I'd bet there is a series resistor on the other end, so that the range of voltages the TVS will allow will not damage anything, so reverse-protection is therefore not needed.